# Outputting list of strings to ostream

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I would like to output list of strings value to ostream.

I can declare and implement overloading function for this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const list<string> &in);
```

... and then write like

```
cout << value;
```

... but there are at least two possible ways to dump list of strings: one string per line or all strings in one line separated by spaces (or maybe other separator).

Is it possible to change dumping function behavior through stream controlling?

I would like to write something like:

```
list<string> lst;
...
cout << print_as_multiline() << lst;
```

... and:

```
list<string> lst;
...
cout << print_as_one_line() << set_separator (", ") << lst;
```

Comment: Why not just `std::copy`? `std::ostream_iterator` lets you control what's between each of them.

Comment: As an attempt of better readability

Comment: string is null terminated, to print_as_one_line, you need to remove `\n`

Comment: Fine, then move it to a function that accepts a string to pass to it.

Comment: The [pretty printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) supports custom delimiters. It might be worth a shot.

Comment: IMO, any attempt to implement such an approach will be overly complicated, simpler to have two functions, `print_multi()`, `print_single()`, which takes the list and the stream and simply iterates through and prints it out... code is clear and intention is clear...

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea… could you test it?
In your operator << implementation file Create a global,static?? variable string Separator= def sep (", ").

Use it in your <<, (and before return reset to def sep?- your decision)

Create a class set_separator, with the implementation of the constructor in the same file as your <<. In this constructor set Separator to the argument.

Define a new operator << for class set_separator, with do nothing, just return the stream.

Similar with multiline output.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for that:
 - Write multiple functions or a function taking a separator as parameter.
 - Attach the separator to the stream. You can use the iostream's `xalloc()` function to allocate a custom property slot (it should be allocated only once and then applies to all streams). You can then use the streams' `iword()` and `pword()` memberfunctions to access the attached info. There is also an event that you can hook into, so a custom function is called when e.g. the stream is destroyed. Use that in order to release dynamically allocated content, in case that is necessary.
 - Create a so-called facet that takes care of the list formatting. This facet is attached to the stream's locale.

My advise: Take the first option, it's the least complicated and most straightforward one. If you need to decide the formatting in one place but actually use it in a completely different place, use the second one. Read Langer&Kreft C++ IOStreams and Locales before you consider the third option. ;)